# how do I open a file from bash when it contains brackets

Tags: bash, filenames, escape-characters

A previous developer on my project created backup copies of files using the format `"filename (date time).extension"` even though the project was under SVN control (don't ask!!!).  I now can't open those files from bash as I receive the error message

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Is there an escape character or quotes that I can use to instruct bash to open the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same as always.

```
cat \(foo\)
cat '(foo)'
```

Comment: thanks.  i think it was actually the spaces causing the issue.  wrapping it in "foo (date time).ext" seems to work